# Graph api get Teams config returning null

Tags: api, graph, microsoft-teams

I have a team with a single channel and a series of tabs. Some tabs link to document libraries on SharePoint sites which I can browse fine. When I run a graph api call to try and get the details of the tabs in the channel with a call such as this

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/myteamid/channels/mychannelid/tabs

I get results looking like this

[Graph api result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gq45O.png)

Some of the tabs come back with valid configuration data including contentUrl, however two of the tabs come back with null in every element of the configuration, despite the fact that they are just pointing to SharePoint document libraries

This is an issue because we want to use PowerShell with the graph api to clone a team to a new team and have all the new tabs configured ready for use, rather than relying on the user to click on each new tab and configure it

Why is the graph api not returning configuration details for these tabs?

Comment: Could you please try to add the sharepoint sites url in valid Domain list within your app manifest?